# Protecting from XSS in escape_javascript() output in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, xss

In an application I am working on, a client-side view is generated based on some records in the database. I am first generating JSON of the records, saving it in a variable in my page, then using JS to build the interface.

The problem is that the records contain user-generated fields, and the application is thus susceptible to XSS. If you let the JSON pass through `escape_html` (by not calling `html_safe` on it), it will screw up the quotes.

To get to the code. In my model:

```
Class Foo
  # ...
  def describe_for_view
    [{:title => "hello", :content => "<script>I.Am.Evil()</script>"}]
  end
end
```

Somewhere in my view:

```
<script>
  var describedForView = $.parseJSON("<%= escape_javascript(@foo.describe_for_view.to_json).html_safe %>");
</script>
```

Then in my javascript:

```
$("body").append("title: " + describedForView[0].title + ", content: " + describedForView[0].content);
```

What I am currently doing is that I am wrapping the access to the user-generated fields with a call to `$.sanitize` as defined by:

```
$.sanitize = function(str) {
  return $("<div/>").text(str).html();
};
```

Things work this way, but I don't think it is clean.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 has a built in [SanitizeHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) which takes a whitelist approach.  I would either call it on user data before persisting it to the database, or in your escape_javascript call:

`escape_javascript(sanitize(some_stuff.to_json))`